# Java appending n headers to a response. I'm using jax-rs/lombok.

Tags: java, jax-rs, lombok

I'm creating a response with code like this:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;

public static Response success(String content) {   
  TestResponse skeletonRsponse = response(content);
  return buildResponse(skeletonRsponse);        
}

public static Response buildResponse(SmartTestResponse skeletonRsponse){
  Response re = Response.status(Status.OK).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity(skeletonRsponse.getContent()).build();
  return re;
}
```

That all works fine.

Now, what I'd like to do is add response headers. I could do something like this:

```
Response.status(Status.OK).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity(skeletonRsponse.getContent()).header("header1", "value1").header("header2", "value2").build();
```

But I'll have a variable amount of headers stored in a map. My question then is what would be the best way to add n headers to my response? I have to pretty much work within the confines of the code that I've shown (the map of all the required headers is available to me wherever I need it). I think I'd run the map with a foreach loop appending as I go but I can't find a code example of how to do the actual appending. Not really sure how to approach this. Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: https://coderanch.com/forums/posts/reqResolved/679121

The problem was that Postman was creating a Request Header 'Content-Length' which I was grabbing and then setting it as a Response Header. However, Postman was also trying to add its own Response Header called 'Content-Length'. This was causing a conflict.